# Why website position on the google is shifting

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I want to know what's the reason behind shifting of website on google is there, whenever I updated the website with the new content.

Whenever I go ahead with the new content, it goes beyond 150 on google.

and after few days it comes to 30

I don't know what should I do to bring it on to the top 5.

Is there any  software which will help in bringing on to the top ?

I m just doing directory submission 5-10 everyday.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Search engines don't rank web sites. They rank web pages. Is the home page's rank fluctuating? Or the content of the new page?

Comment: Home page's rank is fluctuating

Comment: When you say "new content" are you adding new pages, or re-writing content, removing content or just adding to the homepage? Is the market you are in super competitive?

Comment: I m using wordpress-php for my website.  and I create new "Post" every time I add the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

- if you remove any pages make sure there is a redirect to another page
- your page names or [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URLs) urls should be descriptive as to what is on them

Some other things you can do to boost your ranking are:

- participate in forums providing value and ensure you site address is in your signature
- help other bloggers out in your area of expertise by commenting on their posts
- write some guest posts for other sites that reference some of your older posts (don't over do it though; 1 to 2 references max.
- submit your site to directories like [dmoz](http://www.dmoz.org/docs/en/add.html)

The most important part is to continually providing value. Over time people will start linking to your site which really helps your ranking.

Never ever submit your site address to an app, site or whatever that promises to mass submit your site everywhere! This could really hurt your rankings.

Comment: Thanks RDL, I'll go ahead with the suggestion given by you and I hope it'll bring good results.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about "app", I didn't get that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually delete old pages? (and then rename and reupload, or sth)
Do you have a lot of links, bit of unrelated, in your pages? 
Maybe  are you having duplicated content, paragraphs, pages? Too many ads in many pages?

How is your domain? In which kind of hosting it is? It sometimes depends on if hosted in certain kind of hosting, or if the url is of certain kind, if for the domain you are using redirections, cloaking...

A lot of factors can make a site go down, I'd check most of what is usually said to lower it or possibly harm it.
Just some brainstoprming to help.